# alert is not cooperating with input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know to do so that you can create user but I do not want php to find out if there is content in the input or not, why should I have done it with jquery,

The problem is that jquery does not come back and tell me what's wrong? and The problem is that it does not come back and show my Alert in some manner whatsoever. or what I lack of add to it.

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var $opretbruger = $(".opretbruger"),
        $pwd = $("#pass2"),
        $usr = $("#brugernavn");
        $navn = $("#fornavn");
        $efter = $("#efternavn");
        $tjek = $("#tjek");

    $opretbruger.on("submit", function (event) {
        var msg = "Husk ",
            usr = ($usr.val().trim() !== ""),
            pwd = ($pwd.val().trim() !== "");
            navn = ($navn.val().trim() !== "");
            efter = ($efter.val().trim() !== "");
            tjek = ($tjek.val().trim() !== "");

        msg += !usr ? "brugernavn" : "";
        msg += !usr && !pwd ? " og " : "";
        msg += !pwd ? "kodeord" : "";
        msg += !usr && !pwd && !navn ? " og " : "";
        msg += !navn ? "fornavn" : "";
        msg += !usr && !pwd && !navn && !efter ? " og " : "";
        msg += !efter ? "efternavn" : "";
        msg += !usr && !pwd && !navn && !efter && !tjek ? " og " : "";
        msg += !tjek ? "Jeg godkender brugerbetingelserne!" : "";

        (pwd && usr && navn && efter && tjek) || alert(msg);

        return (pwd && usr && navn && efter && tjek);
    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<form name="opretbruger" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" id="opretbruger">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <td>Brugernavn</td>
        <td><input type="email" name="email" class="opretbar" id="brugernavn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="pa2" class="opretbar" id="pass2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Fornavn</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fornavn" class="opretbar" id="fornavn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Efternavn</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="efternavn" class="opretbar" id="efternavn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Betingelserne</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="tjek" id="tjek"> Jeg godkender <a href="/brugerbetingelser/">brugerbetingelserne</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="tilmelddiggratis" value="Opret bruger" class="click opretbruger"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Would have liked it to be so certain email and password missing so it must just come forward and tell it that that lack it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form selector should be `$opretbruger = $('form[name="opretbruger"]')` because `opretbruger` is the name of the form not class

```
var $opretbruger = $('form[name="opretbruger"]')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nbby5/)

Also don't instead of evaluating the validity twice, cache the value like

```
    var valid = pwd && usr && navn && efter && tjek;
    if (!valid) {
        alert(msg);
    }

    return valid;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jn2te/)

Comment: oh okay, it works still does not :(

Comment: @user3117284 check the fiddle.... is it working for you

Comment: You can show the error here: bit.ly/J3Nf3h

Comment: you have a syntax error in the script file `inputform.js` there is a `...` at the last function... which causes the script not to execute

Comment: @user3117284 comment it out or remove it... look at your browser console you can see the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . `

Comment: 'm sorry but I really can not see the error .. Allows you to write it?

Comment: @user3117284 it seems to be working now right

Comment: Yeaaaaa :D Thanks for the god help!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to figure out what this line is supposed to do:

```
 (pwd && usr && navn && efter && tjek) || alert(msg);
```

Did you mean

```
if (pwd && usr && navn && efter && tjek) alert(msg);
```

?

Comment: t does not help, it will not appear in my alert ..

Comment: Right.  My question is: What is this line supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong here but you definitely won't be submitting that form anywhere unless you replace:

```
<form ... action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"
```

with

```
<form ... action="<?php print $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"
```

And change this:

```
var $opretbruger = $(".opretbruger")
```

to this

```
var $opretbruger = $("#opretbruger")
```

And finally make your submit look like this:

```
$opretbruger.on("submit", function (evt) {
    var e = evt || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    // at the bottom - replace return with:
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Comment: It helps in any way :(

Comment: Re-read the answer and add the updates to your code

Comment: you can show the code here: bit.ly/J3Nf3h

Answer (score 0):

Not

```
var $opretbruger = $(".opretbruger"),
```

But

```
var $opretbruger = $("#opretbruger"),
```

As

```
<form ...   id="opretbruger">
```

Comment: It helps in any way. it will not show the still.

Answer (score 0):

Put the variable declarations inside the event function.  Otherwise it's only grabbing the vars once.  Also don't reuse the variables to hold both string and boolean data.

```
$opretbruger.on("submit", function (event) {

   var $opretbruger = $(".opretbruger"),
    $pwd = $("#pass2"),
    $usr = $("#brugernavn");
    $navn = $("#fornavn");
    $efter = $("#efternavn");
    $tjek = $("#tjek");

    var msg = "Husk ",
        usr = ($usr.val().trim() !== ""),
        pwd = ($pwd.val().trim() !== "");
        navn = ($navn.val().trim() !== "");
        efter = ($efter.val().trim() !== "");
        tjek = ($tjek.val().trim() !== "");
```

Style points: use if() instead of short circuits.  Avoid comma.  Makes it confusing to read.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to have a typo in the variable declarations. You are using `;` instead of `,`

```
var $opretbruger = $(".opretbruger"),
        $pwd = $("#pass2"),
        $usr = $("#brugernavn"),
        $navn = $("#fornavn"),
        $efter = $("#efternavn"),
        $tjek = $("#tjek");
```

And also:

```
var msg = "Husk ",
    usr = ($usr.val().trim() !== ""),
    pwd = ($pwd.val().trim() !== ""),
    navn = ($navn.val().trim() !== ""),
    efter = ($efter.val().trim() !== ""),
    tjek = ($tjek.val().trim() !== "");
```

You should try to use jshint to help you against those kind of issue.

Comment: Although you are correct that he SHOULD do this, the way he has it now will only create global variables.  There is nothing syntactically wrong with it.

Comment: Come on, you down vote me for this! The guy is using advanced javascript stuff like (pwd && usr && navn && efter && tjek) || alert(msg); so he should be aware of those kind of issues... But you're totally right, this will not help him solve his problem. I don't have the privilege to comment yet, that would have been a comment instead of a answer.