# alert box appears with the I accept the terms of use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Yesterday I make this post. : [alert is not cooperating with input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714867/alert-is-not-cooperating-with-input)

I got it to work as I want it but it will not take ***#tjek*** in some places so for example if you forget to click on the checkbox so it will not rise up and say "**Hey you are missing is just this checkbox,**"

what is the problem is that **#tjek** does not come back and tell that you are missing all this before we can move forward.

So in other words, it appears, saying "**Jeg godkender brugerbetingelserne**"

Html

```
<form name="opretbruger" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" id="opretbruger">
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <td>Brugernavn</td>
        <td><input type="email" name="email" class="opretbar" id="brugernavn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="pa2" class="opretbar" id="pass2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Fornavn</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fornavn" class="opretbar" id="fornavn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Efternavn</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="efternavn" class="opretbar" id="efternavn"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Betingelserne</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="tjek" id="tjek"> Jeg godkender <a href="/brugerbetingelser/">brugerbetingelserne</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="tilmelddiggratis" value="Opret bruger" class="click opretbruger"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

jQuery:

```
    $(function () {
    var $opretbruger = $('form[name="opretbruger"]'),
        $pwd = $("#pass2"),
        $usr = $("#brugernavn"),
        $navn = $("#fornavn"),
        $efter = $("#efternavn"),
        $tjek = $("#tjek");

    $opretbruger.on("submit", function (event) {
        var msg = "Du mangler ",
            usr = ($usr.val().trim() !== ""),
            pwd = ($pwd.val().trim() !== ""),
            navn = ($navn.val().trim() !== ""),
            efter = ($efter.val().trim() !== ""),
            tjek = ($tjek.val().trim() !== "");

        msg += !usr ? "brugernavn" : "";
        msg += !usr && !pwd ? ", " : "";
        msg += !pwd ? "kodeord" : "";
        msg += !usr && !pwd && !navn ? ", " : "";
        msg += !navn ? "fornavn" : "";
        msg += !usr && !pwd && !navn && !efter ? ", " : "";
        msg += !efter ? "efternavn" : "";
        msg += !usr && !pwd && !navn && !efter && !tjek ? ", " : "";
        msg += !tjek ? "Jeg godkender brugerbetingelserne!" : "";

        var valid = pwd && usr && navn && efter && tjek;
        if (!valid) {
            alert(msg);
        }

        return valid;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of checking the *value* of the checkbox, you need to check the state of the "checked" property:

```
    tjek = $tjek.prop("checked");
```

That'll be `true` if the checkbox is checked, and `false` otherwise.

That checkbox does not have a "value" attribute at all, so the "value" property will always be empty.

Comment: @user3117284 I'm not sure I know what you mean by that. Maybe you should step through your code with the debugger.

Comment: it is the need to find out is whether you have click on the checkbox or not

Comment: @user3117284 yes, and the "checked" property will reflect the setting of the checkbox. If it is checked (looks like ☑) then the "checked" property will be `true`.

Comment: -> I cant really see what you think and see how I should do it?

Comment: @user3117284 I don't know how to be more clear. Your code currently has `$tjeck.val().trim()` and that is wrong. It should be `$tjeck.prop("checked")` and the value of that will be `true` or `false`.

Comment: You mean its here: `tjek = ($tjek.prop("checked"); !== "");`

Comment: No, don't compare to `""` - the value of the "checked" property is **already** either `true` or `false`.

Comment: i make its to : `tjek = ($tjek.prop("checked") !== false);`